# Errors installing packages in new install of spacemacs

Tags: emacs, package, installation, fedora, spacemacs

I've decided to move into the 1970's and try to get to grips with emacs :-) Since I want to use some useful add-ons, I decided to go for spacemacs. Unfortunately, I have had nothing but trouble trying to install it. Since I am totally new to emacs I having real trouble trying to understand the issue - let alone solve it :-(

I am installing on Fedora 30.

As a first step, I have installed basic emacs, version 26.2. I was able to start up emacs with no issue. I then installed spacemacs, using the git command:

```
git clone https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemac ~/.emacs.d
```

I then started emacs using the --insecure option, since I had read about an https issue if this option is not given.

The installation then proceeds and fills the top and bottom windows as shown below (with apologies for the volume of text):

TOP:

```
                                                       0.200.13@26.2 (spacemacs)


                              [S P A C E M A C S]

        [?] [Homepage] [Documentation] [Gitter Chat] [Update Spacemacs]
                  [Update Packages] [Rollback Package Update]
                     [Release Notes] [Search in Spacemacs]

Found 90 new package(s) to install...
--> refreshing package archive: gnu... [3/3]
--> installing package: adaptive-wrap@spacemacs-editing-visual... [4/90]
Package adaptive-wrap is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?
--> installing package: evil@spacemacs-bootstrap... [19/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-anzu@spacemacs-evil... [20/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-anzu (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-args@spacemacs-evil... [21/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-args (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-ediff@spacemacs-evil... [22/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-ediff (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-exchange@spacemacs-evil... [24/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-exchange (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-iedit-state@spacemacs-evil... [25/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-iedit-state (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-indent-plus@spacemacs-evil... [26/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-indent-plus (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-lisp-state@spacemacs-evil... [27/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-lisp-state (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-matchit@spacemacs-evil... [28/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-matchit (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-mc@spacemacs-evil... [29/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-mc (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-surround@spacemacs-evil... [33/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-surround (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-tutor@spacemacs-evil... [34/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-tutor (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-visual-mark-mode@spacemacs-evil... [36/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-visual-mark-mode (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: evil-visualstar@spacemacs-base... [37/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing evil-visualstar (error: (error Package ‘undo-tree-0.1.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: paradox@spacemacs-ui... [71/90]
Package spinner is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?

An error occurred while installing paradox (error: (error Package ‘spinner-1.7.3’ is unavailable))
--> installing package: undo-tree@spacemacs-editing... [83/90]
Package undo-tree is unavailable. Is the package name misspelled?
--> installing package: ws-butler@spacemacs-editing... [90/90]
```

---

BOTTOM:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/andy/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, evil

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

---

Any help most appreciated...

Comment: what does the `--insecure` option do (I don't have that option on emacs 27)?  I would suggest running `package-refresh-contents`, but it looks like that is happening as a first step, so my guess is something to do package archives not refreshing with that option

Comment: The --insecure option forces the package download to use http rather than https and is documented here: http://spacemacs.org/doc/FAQ.html. In fact, it doesn't seem to make any difference in my case. I have also tried entering the 'package-refresh-contents' command per your suggestion but this does not seem to make any difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you don't use `--insecure` and upgrade to Emacs-26.3.
The upgrade should fix your problem, assuming my crystal ball is right that this a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/233

Comment: Thanks Stefan - that did the trick! :-) I had to install emacs from source unfortunately, but it all now seems to work OK. Doncha just love tracking down dependencies by hand :-{

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug in Fedora.

Comment: Since this isn't really a Fedora bug I raised it as an issue on the Spacemacs GitHub. My guess is that this where most folks would go if they have Spacemacs problems - even though it's not really a Spacemacs bug either.

Comment: @Andy: no, it's a problem with Fedora's `emacs` package because it fails to come with the new GNU ELPA key.  They need to update the package (with the keyring distributed in the Emacs-26.3 tarball).

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem:

My issue was that I had emacs 25.x on my system and there were some issues with that verision of emacs. Here are the commands below that fixed my issue.

```
sudo apt autoremove emacs emacs23 emacs24 emacs25
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install emacs26
```